# Runnable JAR file is not running for Cucumber BDD Framework

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have created a Cucumber-Gherkin framework based Maven testing project in Intellij IDEA and the setup looks like this:

[image: Project Structures in Intellij IDEA]

CuckesRunner class looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/001-login.feature"},
        glue = {"syncpilot/Dokumentportal/step_definitions"},
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"html:target/HTMLReports",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
        dryRun = false
        //tags = "@login"
        //tags = ""
)

public class CukesRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        //String[] arguments = {"foo", "bar"};
        io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main();
    }
}
```

When running CukesRunner class, testcases are getting pass with no error, now I need to generate a runnable jar file so that I can execute it from anywhere, so that's why I created main method inside the CukesRunner class and that same main class(CukesRunner) I have added in pom.xml using 'maven assembly plugin' and it looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>io.cucumber.core.cli.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am creating the jar file using following steps:
File>> Project Structure>> Artifacts>> jar(mit modules with dependencies)>> selecting main class which is CukesRunner and clicking on checkbox to include tests also and at the End building it.

Now when i am executing the generated jar file it is showing:

```
WARNING: No features found at classpath:/
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.004s
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use clean install maven command and run through maven not through cucumber runner , you will get a runnable jar with all dependencies

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
    try {
        Main.main(new String[] { 
    

        "-g","com.sadakar.cucumber.common",
        "-g","com.sadakar.cucumber.runner",
                    
        "classpath:features", 
        
        "-t","@SmokeTest",
        
                
        "-p", "pretty", 
        "-p", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json", 
        "-p", "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumberreport.html",
        
        "-m"
    }
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Main method exception : " + e);
}
}
```

The above code worked for me to execute the cucumber tests from runnable jar with test frame work as TestNG.

Executing jar:
java -jar ProductsAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar